# aChartEngine - Is it possible to save the graph as an image without displaying it in the Layout?

Tags: android, image, layout, graph, achartengine

I am trying to create a line graph and saving it as an image that I will use later in the app. But I can't find a way to create the graph and saving it without showing it in the layout first.

If I create the graph like this:

```
// Getting a reference to LinearLayout of the MainActivity Layout
 chartContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_container);

// Creating a Line Chart
    mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer); 


   // Adding the Line Chart to the LinearLayout
    chartContainer.addView(mChart);
```

And then saving it by using:

```
bitmap1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(mChart.getDrawingCache());
```

it works perfectly, but if I omit the chartContainer for the layout I get an  IllegalStateException caused by NullPointerException.

How can I solve this??
Thanks

Comment: How do you pretend to capture a hidden screen?

Comment: Not possible without viewing the screen.

Answer (score 0):

**You can save Image by implementing it in any button action.**

```
 button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

mChart.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = mChart.getDrawingCache();
            File file ,f = null;                    
            if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) 
                {  
                     file =new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Save_Image");
                     if(!file.exists())
                    {
                      file.mkdirs();

                     } 
                     f = new File(file.getAbsolutePath()+file.separator+ "app"+".png");
                }
              FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(f);                                   
              bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 10, ostream);
              ostream.close();

}
    });
```